# Unable to complete the deploy stage in AWS CodePipeline due to a permission error

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Our application scripts are in GitHub which contains a buildspec.yml specifying what the artifacts are and how to build the application source code. We then use Code Pipeline to orchestrate the build and deployment of the application upon any commit on our master branch on GitHub. We are hitting an error at the Deploy stage as below:
[image: CodePipeline deployment stages]

Hitting on 'Details' link and we get this:
[image]

Now the role that we are using for this Code Build and Pipeline is granted 'Administrator Access' as a blanket role to ensure that we're not missing things. However, the permission error puzzles me as to what else is missing.

The only thing we can think of is that we might have set up the deployment stage wrong. See below:
[image: Deployment stage configuration]

Have anyone come across this or had any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but in my case i had a Lambda in the deployment stage, after waiting 20 minutes for the error message i got the following:
[Codepipeline error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYY4d.png)

I added all the permissions needed by the lambda function to interoperate with CodePipeline, and... notified from my lambda code to codepipeline the success or failure of the action.
I guess you may need to do something similar from your ECS container.
I hope it helps, because my deployment stage is different.
Regards.